# Specifying conditions while building an Array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to create an array of links that contains the word "micro"

```
var links = $('a[href*="micro"]');
```

This works great!

Now how do I specify that it should choose links that contain the word "micro" but not if "and" is present any where.

For eg:

```
https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-micro-mistakes/  //Allowed
https://xyz.com.com/2018/09/07/avoid-microproduction-and/  // Reject
https://xyz.com.com/2018/02/17/avoidand-production-micromistakes/  //Reject
https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-production-mismicrotakes/   //Allowed
```

I am unable to figure out how to provide the filter in my script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:not` psuedoselector to exclude `href`s that contain `and`, just like you're using your current selector to find `href`s that contain `micro`:

```js
$('a[href*="micro"]:not([href*="and"])').css({ color: 'orange' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-micro-mistakes/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/09/07/avoid-microproduction-and/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/02/17/avoidand-production-micromistakes/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-production-mismicrotakes/">some link</a>
```

These are vanilla CSS selectors, so it's just as easy to do this in vanilla JS, no need for a big library like jQuery if you don't want:

```js
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="micro"]:not([href*="and"])')) {
  a.style.color = 'orange';
}
```

```html
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-micro-mistakes/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/09/07/avoid-microproduction-and/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/02/17/avoidand-production-micromistakes/">some link</a>
<a href="https://xyz.com.com/2018/05/07/avoid-production-mismicrotakes/">some link</a>
```

Comment: These links are inside a div. I am dynamically rendering some of them visible and some as hidden (display:none). I want to choose only those links whose div are visible. I used the following: $(div:visible 'a[href*="micro"] to select the ones that are visible but this ain't working - I guess due to the fact that I am dynamically hiding the divs, that's why? What's the solution for the same?

Comment: A guess, try putting the `:visible` after the vanilla CSS selector (put it at the very end) so that jQuery can process it in the right order. If that doesn't work, you can `.filter` the collection afterwards to apply the jQuery `:visible` psuedoselector. (`:visible` is a jQuery extension, not a CSS thing)

Comment: You mean like this - 

$('a[href*="micro" div:visible']? or 

$('a[href*="micro"]'.filter('div:visible')?

Comment: Try putting it at the very end of the CSS selector: `a[href*="micro"]:not([href*="and"]):visible`

Comment: Ok help me understand here. I am hiding the div using .hide() via script. Will this still work? I believe jQuery defines an element as visible "if they consume space in the document". An element could have its visibility set to hidden, so it's not actually seen on the page, but :visible would still return the element. There is a difference between something that is visible on the page and has its visibility property set? Am I right?

Comment: `.hide()` is like `display: none`, so they won't be considered as `:visible`.

Comment: I tried it all ways. I even did this:  
var $links = $('a[href*="micro"]');
    $links.filter('div:visible');
    console.log($links.length);

But it still gives count as 5 whereas only 2 divs with links are visible and rest hidden.

Comment: Anyways thanks so much for your help on the original question!

Comment: You need to assign the result of the `.filter` to a variable, or do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oeag5xpc/ Just calling `.filter` alone doesn't have side-effects

Comment: Good info. Btw I went ahead with your first technique a[href*="micro"]:not([href*="and"]):visible and it worked. I was missing a "(" earlier.